# TestNG: Running test programmatically - parameters set on XmlTest object are null when executing test method

Tags: java, junit, testng

I want to run Test Suite programmatically with TestNG.

I created test structurde: XmlSuite -> XmlTest -> TestClass (which extends XmlClass)

I'm doing three things:

- adding parameter to XmlTest with addParameter(String, String)
- setting parameter to TestClass with setParameters(Map)
- setting variable Day in TestClass

But what happens on test execution is when it goes to @Test method the object doesn't have things which I set before.

**Code**

```
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TmpSuite");

        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("TmpTest");
        // Add parameter to XmlTest
        test.addParameter("testParam1", "clock");

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        // Add parameter to XmlClass
        Map<String, String> testClassParameters = new HashMap<>();
        testClassParameters.put("classParam1", "valueOfClassParam1");
        testClass.setParameters(testClassParameters);

        // Set day variable
        testClass.setDay("Friday");
        testClass.setClass(TestClass.class);

        test.setXmlClasses(Arrays.asList(testClass)) ;

        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(Arrays.asList(suite));

        tng.run();
    }
}

public class TestClass extends XmlClass {

    private String day;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Day: " + day);
        System.out.println("LocalParameters: " + getLocalParameters());
        System.out.println("AllParameters: " + getAllParameters());
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Day: null
LocalParameters: {}
------------> Exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are expecting to do is:

```
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add parameter to XmlClass
        Map<String, String> testClassParameters = new HashMap<>();
        testClassParameters.put("classParam1", "valueOfClassParam1");
        testClassParameters.put("day", "Friday");

        XmlClass testClass = new XmlClass();
        testClass.setParameters(testClassParameters);
        testClass.setClass(TestClass.class);    

        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TmpSuite");

        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("TmpTest");
        // Add parameter to XmlTest
        test.addParameter("testParam1", "clock");
        test.setXmlClasses(Arrays.asList(testClass)) ;

        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(Arrays.asList(suite));    
        tng.run();
    }
}

public class TestClass {

    @Parameters({ "day", "testParam1", "classParam1" })
    @Test
    public void test1(String day, String testParam1, String classParam1) {
        System.out.println("Day: " + day);
        System.out.println("testParam1: " + testParam1);
        System.out.println("classParam1: " + classParam1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, something around that. But parameters number might be different for TestClasses which will be abstract. The best would be to pass Map as parameter, but only String are possible. I'd like to have TestClass containing different objects which won't be null on execution.

Comment: You can inject `ITestContext` instead if you prefer but I didn't see how to find class parameters easily because ITestContext provides the <test> view.

Comment: testClass.setParameters(testClassParameters);  gives me compile error setParameteres is not defined for testClass.

Comment: @KaranAhuja Update your testng version. I suppose you are using a very old one.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I am on testng-6.7
should i upgrade ?
I have meanwhile found a work around with 
xmlTest.addParameter("fromMonth", "January");
xmlSuite.setParameters(suiteParameters);

I found it from the google group.

Comment: @KaranAhuja you choose but 6.7 was released in 2012. https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.testng%20AND%20a:testng%20AND%20v:6.7

Comment: Does it work? For me the class is getting parameters that are set at XmlTest and not at XmlClass.